# In a word combined with two morpheme, can I use a adjective in front of the noun?

Tags: word-choice, word

For example, can I change the word 见面 into 见他的面 or 见帅面 or 见这面?

Comment: what does 中国课 mean?  could it be 中文课, anyhow 中国(中文）、家务 are nouns (not adjectives) which are used attributively, of which there is no lack of examples, and it is unclear what they have in common with the earlier examples

Comment: I just know the noun can be modified whether it's a noun or a adjective.

Comment: I've corrected it into 文.

Comment: I've recorrected the question

Comment: Yes (at least for sensible choices of modifies for the noun in question): https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Separable_verb

Comment: comment #1 applies to the earlier version of the question, whose last 2 examples (＂上中国课＂ and ＂操家务练（？）＂were later edited out，上课，操练，like 见面 may all be considered separable verbs，users therefore, (of course prompted by preceding comment) wonder whether ＂word combined with two morpheme" actually means "separable verb（word)" (离合词）

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they can write it in Revelations, must be ok.

启二二4 也要见他的面；他的名字必在他们的额上。

Rev . 22:4 And they will see His face, and His name will be on their forehead.

However, there is a meaning shift from 见面 'meet' and 见他的面 'see his face'. 2. below would not work, which is what you are suggesting, I think.

1。 我们明天和他见面。

2。*我们明天见和他面。

Answer (score 0):

In 见面, 面 usually doesn't mean 'face', and it's like a classifier, referring to 'times of meeting'.

So, we don't usually say 见他的面, 见帅面 or 见这面. 见他的面 might be ok, but better say 见他一面 or 见他（本）人.  You could say: 见他一面(meet him one time)， 见一面(meet once)， 见几面(meet several times)， 见不到（一）面(can't meet even one time).